# How to refer to method inside form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added a `askout` method to the controller, which is a duplicate of the `create` method with a slight change.

I need help referencing the new method in the form in the view. I can only get it to send messages using the `create` and `new` method from the controller.

Messages controller:

```
  def new
    @message = current_user.messages.new
  end

  def create
    @recipient = User.find(params[:user])
    current_user.send_message(@recipient, params[:body], params[:subject])
    flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent!"
    redirect_to :conversations
  end

  def askout
      @recipient = User.find(params[:user])
      current_user.send_message(@recipient, "Let's go...#{@body}", params[:subject])
      flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent!"
      redirect_to :conversations
    end
```

show.html.slim:

```
#ask_me.mfp-hide 
          center
            .message_div
              = form_tag messages_path, method: :post, remote: true, class:'form-horizontal',id: 'message_form', role: 'form'
                = hidden_field_tag :user, @user.id
                .form-group
                  = hidden_field_tag :subject, "#{@current_user} messaged you", class: 'form-control' 
                .form-group
                  = label_tag :body, 'Your Message', class: 'control-label'
                  = text_area_tag :body, nil, placeholder: "Hi, I like your picture and figured I should write you a message and say...", class: 'form-control' 
                br
                = submit_tag 'Send Message', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Routes:

```
  resources :messages
  member do
    post :askout
```

Comment: Do you have a route that points to `messages#askout`?

Comment: @ptd I added the routes to the post. However when I was submitting the form it never created the message.

Comment: Also, in your askout method you refer to `@body`. Do you mean `params[:body]` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below changes will accomplish what you're looking for.

Routes:

```
resources :messages do
  member do
  post :askout
  end
end
```

View:

```
          = form_tag url_for(:controller => 'messages', :action => 'askout'), :method => 'post'
```

Controller:

```
  current_user.send_message(@recipient, "Let's go...#{params[:body]}", params[:subject])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
form_for @recipient, :url => url_for(:controller => 'messages', :action => 'askout')
```

And also update your routes file:

```
resoucres :members do
  member do
  post :askout
  end
end
```